# "Thing becoming vs Thing become" - What is meant by this phrase? What is its origin/Context?

Tags: continental-philosophy, german-philosophy

I've been reading a lot of German classics for the last couple of years, and I keep bumping into the (para)phrase "The thing become" and "The thing becoming". I remember one of the books mentioning Goethe (I think Der Untergang Des Abendlandes).

I've tried Googling it a few times but nothing comes up, so it might just be nothing; But is this a special phrase? If so, what is its meaning beyond its literal meaning and its context? Is it attributed to Goethe somehow?

Comment: The problem of [Being and Becoming](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/spacetime-bebecome/) has its roots in presocratic philosophy and is concerned with the nature of time and change.

Comment: Do you ask about a phrase in German language or in English language? - Because 'The thing become' is not correct in English language; it should read 'The thing becomes' (Singular) or 'The things become' (Plural).

Comment: @nwr Thank you very much for the link; I believe this might be the term that is referred to. Out of curiosity; Do you know if this in any way linked to Goethe?

Comment: @JoWehler Hello Jo, some of the books were actually English translations; I understand that it is a strange wording of the phrases, but I believe the specific phrasing bears a certain meaning. The verb was "Become" and "becoming".

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm not familiar with Goethe's writing, but a quick google search includes Goethe quotes such as “If I accept you as you are, I will make you worse; however, if I treat you as though you are what you are capable of becoming, I help you become that.” This use of the idea of being and becoming is not the same as the philosophical problem of being and becoming.  So perhaps my suggestion is not correct.  It is difficult to decide without further context.

Comment: @BurgerMan If you can provide me with the precise quote in English and the context, then possibly I can find out the original German text (I am a German native). Then I can see whether there is a difference in the German original. Note: 'Der Untergang des Abendlandes' is not by Goethe. The book is much later. The German author is Spengler.